# Rejected react-query mutation causing "Uncaught (in promise)" error

Tags: reactjs, promise, react-query, react-scripts

After upgrading `react-scripts` from v4 to v5, I'm facing a problem with `react-query` ^3.34.8.

I am rejecting a promise within `useMutation` which is causing the runtime error `Uncaught (in promise)`:

```js
// Component.js
import useDeleteMutation from './useDeleteMutation';
  
export default function Component(){
  const { mutateAsync: delete } = useDeleteMutation();
  
  return (
    <button onClick={delete}>Delete</button>
  );
}
```

```js
// useDeleteMutation.js
import { useMutation } from 'react-query';

export default function useDeleteMutation() {
  return useMutation(
    async () => {
      return Promise.reject('Simulate failure');
    },
  )
};
```

Reading [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/13168) and [this](https://github.com/TanStack/query/issues/96) it seems I am missing a try/catch. However I have tried adding them (around the call to `delete()` and around the `Promise.reject` statement) yet the runtime error remains.

Any idea what I'm missing? what else can I wrap in a try/catch? I don't want to just silence the warning in create-react-app's config.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

- you can use `mutate` instead of `mutateAsync` if you don't need access to the returned Promise. It will catch errors internally.
- in v4, you will still see a log statement in the console unless you pass a custom logger that doesn't write to the console. In v5, we will no longer log failed requests to the console because they are not a "warning" that developers should be alerted about.

Comment: Thanks that does seem to work, however we went another direction as we may use the promise later (will post another answer).

Answer (score 0):

Appending `.catch` to the `delete` call, and tweaking what the useMutation hook returns fixed the error:

```js
// Component.js
import useDeleteMutation from './useDeleteMutation';
  
export default function Component(){
  const { mutateAsync: delete } = useDeleteMutation();
  
  return (
    <button onClick={() => { delete().catch(e => {}); }}>
     Delete
   </button>
  );
}
```

```js
// useDeleteMutation.js
import { useMutation } from 'react-query';

export default function useDeleteMutation() {
  return useMutation(
    async () => {
      return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        reject('Simulate failure');
      });
    },
  )
};
```